# Installing dph-examples in Mac OS X 10.7.2

Tags: macos, haskell

I am trying to install [dph-examples](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dph-examples) in mac os x version 10.7.2 and I got this [error](http://hpaste.org/56445). How ever on ghci , I can see 
 
**ghci>import Data.Array.Parallel.  

Data.Array.Parallel.Base            Data.Array.Parallel.Base.DTrace     Data.Array.Parallel.Base.TracePrim  Data.Array.Parallel.Stream**

 but not Data.Array.Parallel , Data.Array.Parallel.Prelude and Data.Array.Parallel.Prelude.Double. I copied the example ( it uses these libraries ) given on [Data-Parallel-Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Data_Parallel_Haskell) and its working fine. My program is compiling and running so my question is, why i am not able to see these library at ghci prompt. Also i am not able to find the reference for sumP function  at the [Data-Array-Parallel](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/dph-par/0.5.1.1/doc/html/Data-Array-Parallel.html). I am using ghc-7.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GHC depends on Xcode 3.2:

> The package requires Xcode 3.2 (in particular, the "Unix Development Support") to be already installed.
>
> — [GHC 7.2.1 download page](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_2_1#macosxintel)

Xcode 3.2 should already come with LLVM, so if it's not already installed, installing it should fix things. If you already have it installed, then your installation might be broken somehow; you could try reinstalling it to make sure. I think Xcode 4 isn't fully supported by GHC yet, so if you have it installed, that might be the problem; you could try uninstalling it and installing 3.2 instead.

Comment: I am using Xcode 4.2.1 . Should  i remove it and install Xcode 3.2 ?

Comment: @keep_learning: It's worth a try, since 3.2 is what the GHC site states as the requirement, and Xcode 4 was quite new when GHC 7.2.1 came out.

Comment: You can likely just install LLVM seperately.

Comment: @monadic Could you please tell me how to do this. Should i download both  LLVM source code and Clang source code. I don't see any binaries for mac os x ( Darwin Macintosh 11.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0: Tue Aug  9 20:56:15 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.24.8~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 ). I mean a small tutorial installing these softwares or any link for this.

Comment: @keep_learning: There's the [official binaries](http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/clang+llvm-3.0-x86_64-apple-darwin11.tar.gz) (from the [LLVM site](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html)), but I'd strongly suggest switching Xcode versions instead; I suspect having two installed LLVM versions would cause some rather painful conflicts.

Comment: @ehird After installing Xcode 3.2 , should i reinstall ghc-7.2.1 ?

Comment: @keep_learning: I don't think you need to; if dph-examples installs fine, then I think it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning: Couldn't figure out LLVM version!
Make sure you have installed LLVM
```

Perhaps you didn't install LLVM? Go install LLVM.